# Make an arraylist method synchronized without using Collections.synchronizedList()

Tags: java, collections

What are the other ways of making an arraylist synchronized without using `Collections.synchronizedList()` ?

Comment: What do you mean?  Why do you want this?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What have you got against the method you mentioned? Describe exactly why that won't work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `Collection.synchronizedList()` just wraps an existing `List` by synchronizing all methods that can be accessed from a client class on a single mutex.

Nothing more nor less, if you want to emulate the behavior, the simplest way is to do exactly the same. But I don't see the point in doing it.

Answer (score 1):

i hope there are 2 ways ,

1. extends arraylist to your own class and override each method make it thread safe to enable synchronization
2. user CopyOnWriteArrayList which is another thread safe version of arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or other concurrent collections from `java.util.concurrent`. Also, `Vector` is in essence synchronized `ArrayList`, but this also means that it's basically the same as `ArrayList` wrapped with `Collection.synchronizedList()`.

If you want us to help you with choosing appropriate collection, please specify details of your task.

Answer (score 0):

[ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) is not a `List` but it is thread safe while accessing  to its elements.